# Evenly spaced divs depending on window size

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small issue with my css here. I'm sure there is a very simple answer but it's been driving me nuts the past few days so I thought I'd post it. So I have 6 divs (2 sets of 3) each set is on it's own line, now the problem I'm faced with is that I can't seem to get them evenly spaced out with an adjustable window, as when the window size changes I'd like the even space to change with it. But I can't seem to get it to work?

```css
.main {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.org_container {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 6%;
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.org_name {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.org_info {
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.btnOpen {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 25%;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <!-- First Div First Line-->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Second Div First Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org2">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Thrid Div First Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org3">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- First Div Second Line-->

  <div class="org_container" id="org4">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Second Div Second Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org5">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Thrid Div Second Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org6">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I would start by putting each set of three columns in their own DIV tag, instead of putting all sets into one big DIV. That way you reduce the problem to keeping three columns in one DIV. The problem is that the border in `.org_container` is added to the widths you have: 32% (= 20% + 2 x 6%). You should not give `.org_container` a border. Instead put another div tag inside and give that a border.

Comment: `as when the window size changes I'd like the even space to change with it` ==> Will be easy with `flexbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

I have used [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for achieving this.

```css
.main {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding:0 5%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.org_container {
  width: 27%;
  border: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6% 0;
}

.org_name {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f0f5;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.org_info {
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.btnOpen {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 25%;
  background-color: #2f8fcb;
  border: 2px solid #2f8fcb;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <!-- First Div First Line-->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Second Div First Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Thrid Div First Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- First Div Second Line-->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Second Div Second Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Thrid Div Second Line -->

  <div class="org_container" id="org1">

    <div class="org_name">

      <p align="center">Name</p>

    </div>

    <div class="org_info">

      <p>Address Line 1</p>

      <p>Address Line 2</p>

      <p>Address Line 3</p>

      <p>Post Code</p>

      <p>Telephone Number</p>

      <button class="btnOpen">Open</button>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: If you run the code you'll see that the first div has a smaller `margin-left` compared to the third div's `margin-right`. I'm trying to get them all equal.

Comment: @MattHutch can you divide the contents into two div containing 3 div.?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't no. As I'm using php `while` to pull the data from my db for the divs.

Comment: @MattHutch check my answer it will help you.